# Macro to move number with dash to new cell

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I am trying to get a macro to move numbers with a "-".

I have a column `E` with a list of numbers

```
54525841-1
454152
1365466
1254566-1
1452577-1
```

I want a macro to move all the numbers that have a dash or hyphen at the end to column C. 
So I would need `E1` 54525841-1 to be moved to `C1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by this:

```
Sub MoveDash()  
  x = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For Each Cell In Range("E2:E" & x)
     If InStr(Cell, "-") <> 0 Then
        Cell.Offset(, 1) = Cell
        Cell.ClearContents
     End If
  Next Cell
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change "Sheet1" to the name of the sheet where your data is.

This looks through every cell (with data) in the E column and moves the value accross to the C column if it contains a dash.

```
Sub MoveDashes()
  Dim Sheet As Worksheet
  Dim Index As Long
  Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  For Index = 1 To Sheet.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, Sheet.Cells(Index, "E"), "-") > 0 Then
      Sheet.Cells(Index, "C") = Sheet.Cells(Index, "E").Value
      Sheet.Cells(Index, "E").Value = ""
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I used the macro and nothing happen.

Comment: is your worksheet named "Sheet1"? If not, you need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: There is no need to reference the sheet if the macro is being run while the sheet in question is the active sheet. A for each loop would be more effecient than a for loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a macro? How about Advanced Filter?

Your numbers are in column E. Let's assume they have a header.

```
E1: Number

E2: 54525841-1

E3: 454152

E4: 1365466

E5: 1254566-1

E6: 1452577-1
```

In a separate area of your worksheet (let's say column G) put the following criteria:

```
G1: Number

G2: *-*
```

Your advanced filter criteria would look like this:

[image: advanced filter criteria]

Anything with a "-" in it will be copied to column C.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without VBA, but here is an efficient way to do it using the dictionary object.

```
Sub MoveNumbersWithDash()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim varray As Variant
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

lastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
varray = Range("E1:E" & lastRow).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)
    If InStr(1, varray(i, 1), "-") <> 0 Then
        dict.Add i, varray(i, 1)
    End If
Next

Range("C1").Resize(dict.Count).Value = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.items)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**How it works:**
The major theme here is avoiding calls to Excel (like a for each loop). This will make the function blazing fast (especially if you have tens and thousands of rows) and more efficient. First I locate the last cell used in E then dump the entire row into a variant array in one move. Then I loop through each element, checking if it contains a "-", if it does, I add it to a dictionary object. *POINT*: Add the entry as the ITEM, not KEY. This makes sure that we allow for duplicates. The variable I will be unique for each entry, so I use that as the key. Then I simple dump the entire array of cells with "-" into column C.

**Why Dictionary?**
The dictionary object is very fast and comes with 2 really great functions: .Keys and .Items. These will return an array of all the keys or items in the dictionary, which you can use the Transpose function on to dump an entire column of values into Excel in one step. Super efficient.